# Double Buffering and reflecting variable changes in C++/OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I want allow users to change the values of the prob array through the console and then reflect those changes onto the window.

I know I must use double buffering so I have set the display mode in my main function as

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
```

Below is my display function:

```
void display () {
    // declare some variables that will be used
    int point_num = 8000000;
    double r, x, y, x1 = 0, y1 = 0;
    double prob[4] = {0.01, 0.19, 0.20, 0.60};

    // clear the window
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    for (int i = 0; i < point_num; i++) {
        r = drand48(); // generate a random number between 0.0 - 1.0

        // compare the random number we get to the if statement below and get the appropriate x and y values
        if (r < prob[0]) {
            x = ((0.2 * x1) + (4.4 * y1) + 7.5) / ((0.2 * x1) + (8.8 * y1) + 15.4);
            y = ((-0.3 * x1) + (-4.4 * y1) + -10.4) / ((0.2 * x1) + (8.8 * y1) + 15.4);
        }
        else if (r < prob[1]) {
            x = ((-32.5 * x1) + (5.81 * y1) + -2.9) / ((-128.1 * x1) + (-24.3 * y1) + -5.8);
            y = ((122.9 * x1) + (-0.1 * y1) + -19.9) / ((-128.1 * x1) + (-24.3 * y1) + -5.8);
        }
        else if (r < prob[2]) {
            x = ((96.5 * x1) + (35.2 * y1) + 5.8) / ((134.8 * x1) + (30.7 * y1) + 7.5);
            y = ((-131.4 * x1) + (-6.5 * y1) + 19.1) / ((134.8 * x1) + (30.7 * y1) + 7.5);
        }
        else {
            x = ((19.05 * x1) + (0.72 * y1) + 1.86) / ((5.63 * x1) + (2.01 * y1) + 20.0);
            y = ((-0.15 * x1) + (16.9 * y1) + -0.28) / ((5.63 * x1) + (2.01 * y1) + 20.0);
        }

        x1 = x;
        y1 = y;
        // plot the points
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2d(x1, y1);
        glEnd();
    }

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

I know how to interact with the user through on the console and change the variable values but I just don't understand how to reflect those changes on the window while to program is running using OpenGL. I tried using a while loop before the for loop to allow users to change the values of the prob array but this didn't work for me. Any ideas on how I can achieve what I want?

Comment: *this didn't work for me.* - why specifically?

Answer (score 0):

> but I just don't understand how to reflect those changes on the window

You need state. Declare a variable for your program to use, change it when console events are processed, use that variable to display things.

You'll most probably need a threading solution for this, unless you can interleave console buffer interaction with rendering.

Comment: OP's problem is, that he wants to interact with stdio, which clashes with the needs of GLUT's main loop.

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas on how I can achieve what I want?

The most easy solution would be spawning an extra thread that does interaction with stdio. If you do it in the GLUT mainloop (thread), everytime a operation on stdio blocks, the whole program freezes. This is definitely not what you want.

Another option is using solely nonblocking operations on stdio, polling if input is available and passing that to a statefull parser. The problem with that is, that you'll likely get only one character at a time, which, of course, doesn't go so well with functions like `fscanf`, `fgets` and similar.

Comment: `sscanf` to the rescue, though. But I'm pretty sure someone has already written a cross-platform async IO library.